# Wanted to hide the parameters on javascript form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My URL looks like the below format:

```
http://hostname:8080/search/?N=4294967292&Ntt=abcdef&add=1&Nr=AND(OR(a:abc,a:def,a:ghi),OR(b:abc,b:def,b:ghi));
```

I am submitting a form through javascript submit. I wanted to hide the Nr parameter value while submit the form.

My piece of code below:

```
$(".apply-btn").click(function(){   
    var nr=loadQuery();
    var submitUrl = window.location.href;
    submitUrl=submitUrl+nr;
    $('#myForm').attr('action',submitUrl);
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

any help on this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You are asking the **user's** browser to send data to a server. The user can inspect that data.

The closest you could come would be to make a POST request instead (by submitting the form with the data in actual form fields instead of generating a custom action via JS). The information would still be visible in the Net tab of the developer tools that come as standard in most browsers these days.

Comment: my form method is POST only...but i don't know still the Nr parameter is showing on the URL bar...plz help me out..

Comment: @Maniram: Because you put it there: `submitUrl=submitUrl+nr;` / `$('#myForm').attr('action',submitUrl);`

Answer (score 1):

1. create a hidden field in the form with the name `Nr`
2. set the value of the hidden field to the value of `nr` (instead of appending `nr` to the URL)
3. set the `method` attribute of the form to `POST`
4. set the `action` attribute of the form to the value of `window.location.href`
5. submit the form

Comment: 0. Use `method="POST"` *Edit*: Ah, you've added it as 3. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use a POST request plus SSL to encryp your requests. As Quentin said, this also would not stop the user from seeing your request with the developers tool bar, but during the submission it is encrypted.